# can a category,between any two of whose objects there are maps,not necessarily unique, be regarded as a preordered set?

Tags: category-theory

In my book on category theory it has been stated that a category in which for each pair of its objects there is "at most" one map between them can be regarded as a preordered set. I do not know the logic behind the expression "at most" here,since I think this hypothesis can be removed without losing the content. Can anybody illustrate the matter?

Comment: Preorders have no way to express multiple different relationships between their elements.

Comment: @KevinCarlson I just changed the order. What about this new situation?

Comment: I make the same comment. If there are parallel morphisms in the category, you would have to identify them to model it as a preorder.

Comment: @KevinCarlson Suppose I "define" an order on the category as explained above,except that the "at most" hypothesis is removed. it is still a preorder

Comment: What's the definition of your order? $x\leq y$ for two objects of the category, if and only if...

Comment: @KevinCarlson if and only if there is a morphism between them. it is a preorder.

Comment: Ah yes, sure. But that throws away a lot of information: you can't recover the category from that. That's the point of the phrase "can be seen as," I.e. "Is isomorphic to."

Comment: @KevinCarlson you are right, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will use the following conventions:

1). A *preordered set* is a pair $(X,\le_X)$, where $X$ is a set and $\le_X$ is a reflexive transitive relation on it. The category of preordered sets and monotonic functions between them is denoted by $\mathbf{Preord}$.

2). A *category* is a $6$-tuple $(\text{Obj}(A),\text{Mor}(A),\text{dom}_A,\text{cod}_A,\text{comp}_A,\text{id}_A)$, where $\text{Obj}(A)$ and $\text{Mor}(A)$ are sets and others are functions with additional properties. The category of categories and functors between them is denoted by $\mathbf{Cat}$.

Let $A$ be a category, $a$ and $b$ be its objects. Then denote
$$
\text{hom}_A(a,b)=\{f\in Mor(A)|\quad \text{dom}(f)=a,\quad \text{cod}(f)=b\}.
$$

**Definition.** The category $A$ is called a *preorder* iff for every two objects $a$ and $b$ of $A$ we have $|\text{hom}_{A}(a,b)|=1$ or $|\text{hom}_{A}(a,b)|=0$, where $|\text{hom}_{A}(a,b)|$ denotes the cardinal number of the set $\text{hom}_{A}(a,b)$. Equivalently, for every two objects $a$ and $b$ the set $\text{hom}_{A}(a,b)$ contains no more than one element/at most one element.

3). The category of all preorders (not preordered sets!) is a full subcategory of $\mathbf{Cat}$; denote it by $\mathbf{CatPreord}$.

Now the main statement is that categories $\mathbf{Preord}$ and  $\mathbf{CatPreord}$ are equivalent. The equivalence $\mathcal{F}\colon \mathbf{Preord}\to \mathbf{CatPreord}$ defines in the following way: $$\mathcal{F}(X,\le_X)=(X,\le_X,\text{pr}_1,\text{pr}_2,\text{tr}_{X},\text{ref}_X),$$

where $\text{pr}_1$ and $\text{pr}_2$ denote the restrictions of the first and the second projections of the product $X\times X$, the functions $\text{tr}_{X}$ and $\text{ref}_X$ define obviously by transitivity and reflexivity of $\le_X$. The inverse equivalence $\mathcal{G}\colon \mathbf{CatPreord}\to \mathbf{Preord}$ defines in the following way: $$\mathcal{G}(\text{Obj}(A),\text{Mor}(A),\text{dom}_A,\text{cod}_A,\text{comp}_A,\text{id}_A)=(\text{Obj}(A),\le_A),$$

where $\le_A$ is such relation that $a\le_Ab$ iff $|\text{hom}_A(a,b)|=1$.

**Edit 3.** You ask why we can't remove a hypothesis about "at most one map". The answer is that if you add to $\mathbf{CatPreord}$ some other categories with more than one arrow between two objects, then it becomes not equivalent to $\mathbf{Preord}$. That's why we can't omit the requirement about "at most one map".

**Edit 2.** Sorry for my inattantiveness at the first time. I have added some actual information to this answer. **Kevin Carlson** gave a good explanation in comments. I want to add that a preorder (category) *is not* a preordered set. Such arguments are true only with regarding the categories of appropriate objects (see Edit 1).

**Edit 1.** Of course, this definition is motivated by the connection between such categories and preordered sets. The rigorous expression of such connection is that the category $\mathbf{Preord}$ of preordered sets is equivalent to the full subcategory of category $\mathbf{Cat}$, whose objects are preorders.

Comment: The asker appears already to know the definition.

Comment: @KevinCarlson Thanks, sorry, I read the question inattentively. But I have added an actual answer to it.

Comment: I think I know what you mean, that every category has a subcategory with |\text{hom}_{A}(a,b)|=1 or |\text{hom}_{A}(a,b)|=0, and it means that this subcategory is a preordered set. but how can I see that a preordered set is a category?

Comment: @math_stud It means something different. Let me repeat: the category with any property _can't be_ a preordered set, because the preordered set is a set with a relation on it, but a category is a pair of sets with four functions. The statement "category with such property _is_ a preordered set" is nothing but a statement about the equivalence of the abovementioned categories.

Comment: @math_stud I think I should include the explicit construction of this equivalence into the answer. Wait a few minutes, please.

Comment: @math_stud Now it's done. Let me know if something is not clear.

Comment: @math_stud Now I think that "Edit 3" is a reasonably good answer to your original question.

Comment: thank you so much, My problem has been solved now @Oskar